# QListView not adding Items

Tags: qt, symbian, qt-creator

I installed the Nokia Qt SDK and made a new project which involved a user interface.

Then I referred to a particular video, *[Creating interactive QT hello world GUI application using QT Creator.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QLT7oEt6gLE&feature=related)*

Now I am not able to add items in list view as there is no function to do that.

Is there some other function to do it?

Comment: Doesn't see QListView in this video. Wrong link maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add rows:

```
ui->listview->model()->insertRow ( int row)
```

or

```
ui->listview->model()->insertRows ( int row, int count)
```

Both methods return true if the rows were successfully inserted.

To set data (for each cell):

```
ui->listview->model()->setData(ui->listview->model()->index ( int row, int column),QVariant value);
```

Comment: Hey hector how can i add a text from LineEdit in a row of ListView.I need to add this (ui.lineEdit->text()) in each row... How to do tht???

Comment: @Coder_sLaY i think this will do `ui->listview->model()->setData(ui->listview->model()->index ( row, column),ui.lineEdit->text());`

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "There is no function to do that" ?

Have you already looked into the [Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/classes.html)? There is also a [QListWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qlistwidget.html) where you can directly add widgets. More useful is the [QListView](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qlistview.html) you mentioned, for which you should have a look at [Qt Model/View Programming](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/model-view-programming.html) first.

Comment: I mean in the video it showed that in order to add items in the Listview,he used ui.listview->addItem(ui.lineEdit->text()); which i am not able to use in QT 4.6 as when i use ui->listview->? ,the addItem is missing.....